# Upload bitmap file to server using volley and codeigniter

Tags: android, codeigniter, android-volley

I am using volley to upload my bitmap file to the server. In server side, i'm using codeigniter framework to do that job but i've got response from the server when I trying to upload the file that says,

> "you did not select a file to upload"

here is the code

**Volley**

```
 public void uploadImage(final Context context, final Bitmap bitmap) {
        String url = "https://zenosama1111.000webhostapp.com/Upload/do_upload";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("thumbnail", bitmapToString(bitmap));
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

**server side**

```
 public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './thumbnails/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 160;
                $config['max_height']           = 100;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('thumbnail'))
                {
                        echo false;
                }
                else
                {
                      echo true;
                }
                 $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                 echo json_encode($error);
        }
```

other tutorials are using pure php code to upload a file but not in codeigniter.. 
somebody know how can i fix this problem?

Comment: if you are using bitmap to upload the image
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
server side problem 'upload' is not use in this line use the file path and replace 'upload'

Comment: I am very familiar with codeigniter upload library but not so familiar with android. I see this line `bitmapToString` which leads me to believe that you should be using file put contents on the `$_POST['thumbnail']` field. CI expects `thumbnail` be an image from the `$_FILES` field where `thumbnail` is the name of the field. If you `print_r($_FILES)` I bet there isn't anything.

Comment: @Alex I tried this code to test `$this->upload->do_upload($this->input->post('thumbnail'))` then the response was a long string that only computer can read. maybe i should do pure php instead of using CI library to do this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `$this->upload->do_upload($this->input->post('thumbnail'))` or `$this->upload->do_upload('thumbnail')` won't work.

`do_upload` will *only* work with an item from the `$_FILES` array (different than post array) and the parameter of `do_upload($param)` must be the fieldname of the file input.

e.g. `<input name="userfile" type="file">` => `do_upload('userfile')`

It isn't intended to be used the way you are using it as your item is in the post array. Hence maybe a `file_put_contents($filename, $this->input->post('thumbnail'));` would work for your needs.

If you could get the item to be in the `$_FILES` array then you might have a chance of using the CI upload library.